# Something wrong with my hole

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, tracking

I am doing the [Introduction to Camera Tracking in Blender](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/) tutorial by Blender Guru.

[image]

Somehow, I managed to mess something up, and supposedly hidden parts of the hole are showing. I don't understand where I went wrong. Thoughts?

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the mask (the ground plane) is not big enough and therefore can't mask out the wall of the pit going down into the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jagged ground plane isn't big enough. Use the following procedure to fix it.

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*.
2. Your outer ring should already be selected (it is in the .blend). If it is not, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select the edge loop:

[image]

3. Key <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the edge loop up until you can't see the tube any more.

[image]

4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.

Comment: btw ...your answer did do the trick, but I must say that I am not understanding what I am doing. Is this "jagged ground plane" a sort of mask ?

Comment: @OldMan Yes. The compositing makes it so. If my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You can also mix the material of the sides of the hole with a *holdout* shader while using the *backfacing* output of a *geometry* node as the *fac* input of the *mix shader*.

Without the holdout shader:

[image]

With the holdout shader:

[image]

Comment: The OP didn't help by tagging the post as __Cycles__, but the .blend is in BI.

Comment: If you download the .blend it is in cycles.